# Grepping one of "reg query" result values

Tags: windows, cmd

In order to get the current Office installation path,
I set up this line

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WINWORD.EXE"
```

and the result is:

```
(Default)    REG_SZ    C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office16\WINWORD.EXE
Path    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\
useURL    REG_SZ    1
SaveURL    REG_SZ    1
```

How to grep out the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\" in a variable? 
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Hint: use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output of `reg query` and to split strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the command line

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\winword.exe" /v Path
```

just the string value of `Path` is output which means on Windows XP:

```
 
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\winword.exe
    Path    REG_SZ  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\
```

So this output starts with an empty line, a header of reg.exe version 3.0, one more empty line, the queried registry key and the queried registry value `Path` if found at all in Windows registry under specified key. There is a tab character between `Path` and `REG_SZ` and one more tab character between `REG_SZ` and the path string. The line with `Path` starts with four spaces.

On Windows Vista and later Windows versions the output is:

```
 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\winword.exe
    Path    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\
```

This output starts with an empty line like on Windows XP. But output is next already the queried registry key without any additional header. Last the line with queried registry value `Path` is output if found at all in Windows registry under specified key. The last line starts also with four spaces like on Windows XP. But there are four spaces between `Path` and `REG_SZ` and four spaces between `REG_SZ` and the path string instead of horizontal tabs.

This means for getting the path string using command **FOR** with option `/F`:

1. The first two lines of output of command **REG** can be always skipped.
2. It is necessary to check if third line contains already value `Path` or one more non empty line needs to be processed to have a batch file working also on Windows XP.
3. The last line has space or tab separated the strings `Path`, `REG_SZ` and the path string which could contain also 1 or more spaces or any other character allowed in a folder name.

The batch file code for this task:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\winword.exe" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "Path" if not "%%~C" == "" set "OfficePath=%%~C" & goto FoundPath
)
echo Could not determine MS Office path. MS Office is most likely not installed.
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:FoundPath
rem Remove backslash at end of path if there is one at all.
if "%OfficePath:~-1%" == "\" set "OfficePath=%OfficePath:~0,-1%"
echo MS Office is installed in: "%OfficePath%"
rem Other command using environment variable OfficePath.
```

The command **FOR** executes in a background process started with `cmd.exe /C` the command line (with `%SystemRoot%` already expanded):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\winword.exe" 2>nul
```

The output of this command process (= `reg.exe`) written to handle **STDOUT** is captured by **FOR**.

**REG** outputs to handle **STDERR** an error message if either the specified registry key or the specified registry value does not exist at all in Windows registry. This error output is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it. Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `reg` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The command **FOR** could have nothing to process in case of registry key or registry value not found by **REG** resulting in execution of the command lines below the **FOR** loop informing the batch file user about this use case.

Otherwise command **FOR** skips because of `skip=2` the first two captured lines which means on Windows Vista and later the first line processed by **FOR** is already the line containing `Path`. On Windows XP the third line being an empty line is ignored by **FOR** and the next line with queried registry key is processed next.

The line is split up because of `tokens=1,2*` and the default delimiters space/tab into 3 substrings.

On Windows Vista and later Windows:

1. `Path` is assigned to specified loop variable `A`.
2. `REG_SZ` is assigned to next loop variable `B` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).
3. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\` is assigned to loop variable `C`.
   This third string is not further split up on spaces/tabs because of `*`.

On Windows XP the first line tokenized by **FOR** results in:

1. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App` being assigned to specified loop variable `A` and
2. `Paths\winword.exe` being assigned to next loop variable `B`.
3. Nothing is assigned to loop variable `C` because there is no more string on processed line.

A case-insensitive string comparison of value of loop variable `A` is made with fixed string `Path` to verify if **FOR** processed already the right line with `Path` value. On Windows Vista and later Windows versions this is already true on first line tokenized by **FOR**. On Windows XP this condition is first false and **FOR** processes therefore the next line now assigned the same strings to the loop variables `A`, `B` and `C` as on Windows Vista and later Windows versions.

On a true condition the path string assigned to loop variable `C` and not being an empty string is assigned to environment variable `OfficePath` with removing enclosing double quotes if the path string is enclosed at all in `"`. And next a jump is made to label `FoundPath` exiting the loop and continue batch file execution in code block on having the MS Office path.

In this code block first a backslash at end of path is removed if there is one at all to have assigned to environment variable `OfficePath` always the path string without a backslash at end independent on path string in registry not having or having a backslash at end using string substitution.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Answer (score 0):

From `cmd.exe` if you run `reg query /?` there is a specific switch that stands out.

```
/v       Queries for a specific registry key values.
         If omitted, all values for the key are queried.
```

When looking at your complete output, you are very specifically requiring the registry key value `Path`

So by Simply running:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WINWORD.EXE" /v Path
```

we get less noise to deal with.

With that logic, here is the batch which simply uses the `:` of the path string extracted as the delimiter and then joining `%%a` being C Drive, with `%%b` being rest of the path after `:` and we simply just join them again with the colon.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WINWORD.EXE" /v Path') do (
    set result=%%a
    set result=!result:~-1!
    set output=!result!:%%b
)
echo !output!
```

Comment: Nice solution as long as the path to Microsoft Word does not contain an exclamation mark which is interpreted on line `set result=%%a` as begin/end of an environment variable reference with delayed expansion. A solution without usage of delayed expansion at least before this line would be better.

Comment: ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` are all possible in a folder or file name. This should be always taken into account if a batch file is written for running on various Windows PCs on which the path to a specific folder/file or the name of a folder/file is not fixed. Otherwise the batch file works on 99.999999% of all computers, but fails on the very small amount of remaining computers without knowing why not working on those machines. An installation/update batch file should really work with any folder/file names. Nothing is more frustrating for a user than an installation not working.

Comment: @Mofi, I have not ever seen a MS Office Path with any special character.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the (javascript) regex `.:(?!.*:).*`

What this captures is:

```
.:                - Drive letter
  (?!.*:)         - Not followed by other colons (illegal in Windows paths)
         .*       - Followed by the path
```